# Implementation Attacks on Hashes

Tags: hash, attack

So I am familiar with attacking implementations of block ciphers via side channel attacks, cache-timing attacks, etc.

What implementation attacks are there against hashes or hashed based functions (e.g. MACs, DRBGs, etc.)?

Comment: Why the close votes?

Comment: since many hash functions use some block cipher design at their core, the same attacks against block ciphers are also useful against hash functions (within limits)

Comment: @RichieFrame Sounds like an answer more than a critique on the question. Or do we consider lists as off topic? (Have to defend my fellow owl :) )

Comment: @RichieFrame hello! So should l look at cache timing attacks and side channel attacks?  What literature is out there about this for hasing?